# How do I save checkbox values from Custom module in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi, drupal-forms

How do I save the status of checkboxes using the hook_submit?

hook_form:

```
$versionArray = array('ver 1.7.0.0-beta1' => 'ver 1.7.0.0-beta1', 'ver 1.6.2.0' => 'ver 1.6.2.0', 'ver 1.5.1.0' => 'ver 1.5.1.0', 'ver 1.4.2.0' => 'ver 1.4.2.0', 'ver 1.3.3.0' => 'ver 1.3.3.0');

$form['mage']['version'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Select'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $versionArray
);
```

hook_submit:

```
....
$node->field_checkboxes[0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['mage']['version'];
....
node_save($node)
```

I have got all my other fields saving correctly, but these fields remain blank.

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your submit function try to use the following code

```
$selected = array();
foreach($form_state['values']['version'] as $a => $b)
{
    if((string)$b != "0")
    {
         $selected[] = $b;
    }
}
variable_set("var_selected", $selected);
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Ok will give this a go shortly and let you know how I got on. Thanks

Comment: Really glad it helped... -Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple:

```
$save_array = array_filter($form_state['values']['mage']['version']);
    $p=0;
        foreach ($save_array as $a => $b) {
            $node->field_checkboxes['und'][$p++]['value'] = $b; 
        }

...
node_save($node);
```